# How to access data on nested List type class

Tags: c#, list, class, nested

Based on the following code, how can I access a class List inside another one.

I can access 'datatosend' items fine, but as soon as I reach datagroupProject which is instantiated inside of dataGroup I have no idea how to get the values from datagroupProject  and datagroupCabs.

How can get and store the values so I can use them?

```
foreach (dataGroup r in datatosend)
{
    string tmpusrn = r.User;
    string tmpNumProj= r.???

...

do something...

}
```

This is where I'm storing the data:

```
datatosend.Add(new dataGroup()
                            {

                                User = cUnum,
                                UserName = cUname,
                                Project = new List<datagroupProject>()
                                {
                                       new datagroupProject
                                       {
                                           NumProj = cProNum,
                                           headers = new List<datagroupCabs>()
                                           {
                                               new datagroupCabs
                                               {
                                                   invoice = tmpinvoice,
                                                   datainv = tmpdate,
                                                   provider = tmpProov


                                               }
                                           }
                                       }


                                }


                            });
```

This is how I created the classes:

```
public class dataGroup
        {
            public string User { get; set; }
            public string UserName { get; set; }

            public List<datagroupProjects> Project { get; set; }

        }

        public class datagroupProject
        {
            public string NumProj { get; set; }
            public List<datagroupCabs> headers { get; set; }

        }

        public class datagroupCabs
        {
            public string invoice { get; set; }
            public string datainv { get; set; }
            public string provider { get; set; }
            public List<datagrouplines> refs { get; set; }

        }
```

And here is the whole thing in case it's needed:

```
namespace testinv
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            _GLOBALS.InitAll();
            GetUsersData();
        }

        public class dataGroup
        {
            public string User { get; set; }
            public string UserName { get; set; }

            public List<datagroupProjects> Project { get; set; }

        }

        public class datagroupProject
        {
            public string NumProj { get; set; }
            public List<datagroupCabs> headers { get; set; }

        }

        public class datagroupCabs
        {
            public string invoice { get; set; }
            public string datainv { get; set; }
            public string provider { get; set; }
            public List<datagrouplines> refs { get; set; }

        }



        public static void GetUsersData()
        {


            Console.WriteLine("Init");

            string cUnum = "";
            string cUname = "";
            string cProNum = "";
            List<dataGroup> datatosend = new List<dataGroup>();
            List<datagroupProject> datatosendproj = new List<datagroupProject>();
            List<datagroupCabs> datatsendCabs = new List<datagroupCabs>();

            DataTable dtUsers = new DataTable();
            dtUsers = BSTOOLS.GetUserData("");

            foreach (DataRow u in dtUsers.Rows)
            {



                cUnum = u.ItemArray[0].ToString();
                cUname = u.ItemArray[1].ToString();


                DataTable dtProjects = new DataTable();
                dtProjects = BSTOOLS.GetProjects(cUnum);

                foreach (DataRow p in dtProjects.Rows)
                {

                    cProNum = p.ItemArray[0].ToString();
                    DataTable dtlines = new DataTable();

                    dtlines = BSTOOLS.DistinctGetDeliveryNotesLines(cProNum);

                    foreach (DataRow l in dtlines.Rows)
                    {
                        string tmpinvoice = "";
                        string tmpdate = "";
                        string tmpProov = "";


                        string tmpiClave = l.ItemArray[0].ToString();

                        DataTable resultCab = new DataTable();
                        resultCab = BSTOOLS.checkifFlow(tmpiClave);

                        if(resultCab.Rows.Count  > 0)
                        {

                            foreach (DataRow c in resultCab.Rows)
                            {
                                tmpinvoice = c.ItemArray[0].ToString();
                                tmpdate = c.ItemArray[1].ToString();
                                tmpProov = c.ItemArray[2].ToString();
                            }

                            datatosend.Add(new dataGroup()
                            {

                                User = cUnum,
                                UserName = cUname,
                                Project = new List<datagroupProject>()
                                {
                                       new datagroupProject
                                       {
                                           NumProj = cProNum,
                                           headers = new List<datagroupCabs>()
                                           {
                                               new datagroupCabs
                                               {
                                                   invoice = tmpinvoice,
                                                   datainv = tmpdate,
                                                   provider = tmpProov


                                               }
                                           }
                                       }


                                }


                            });
                        }




                    }


                }           

            }

        }



    }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

[Edits for clarification]

@Bosco
@Mong Zhu

Basically what I need is for each user in datagroup, loop through his projects in datagroupProject getting the project and all the items in datagroupCabs(this is another List class inside datagroupproject). So it would end up with something like this:

```
user1
      project1
               inv1
               inv2
      project2
               inv1
user2
...
```

I can access datagroupProject and get the value but how can i access the list datagroupCabs inside of it and loop through it?
Hope this clarifies what I need. 
Again, thanks for your time.

Comment: It depends on how and what you want to access inside of the `datagroupProject` you can still loop through it since it is a list or use linq.

Comment: You have a collection of items, and apparently you want to extract only 1 numer in this line: `string tmpNumProj= r.???`. At least this is what it seems to me. You need to be clear about which of the items you want to extract and take the `NumProj`. Can you tell us this? the first? the last? are they all the same?

Comment: "how can I access a class List inside another one." Since it is a normal property you can access it like any other property: `r.Project`. Then you need to know which element you want to index. Choosing an element at a certain position is done by `[index]` like `r.Project[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to get the First value you added:

```cs
string tmpNumProj= r.Project?.FirstOrDefault()?.NumProj ?? string.Empty;
```

You need to add

```cs
using System.Linq;
```

to the head of the file.

But this only works for the first item.
Looks like you are new to C# just check some documentations and tutorials.

### EDIT:

I added i full teaching solution for everyone who dont know how to access lists in lists and how to do it with linq.

See my snipped at: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1886702

Comment: Hi, I was using more 'traditional' ways to access it. But thanks for the idea. Based of that how can I get the info. inside datagroupCabs which is another list class inside r.Project and loop through it?

Comment: Just a foreach loop in a foreach loop

Comment: But a second foreach of what? As I had to create the data with `code` headers = new List<datagroupCabs>()
         {
          new datagroupCabs
          {  ... I dónt think I can access it that way, right?

Comment: I updated my Answer. I created a snipped with a solution using Test data to teach you how to access lists in lists and their properties and how to do it with linq. Hope this will be helpful to anyone who just starts with c#.
Nice tipp: nearly the same things can be done in javascript with their prototype functions.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now. Thanks a lot for you time.